# while downloading the object from amazon s3 i cant able to download it to diffrent folder rather then the file uploaded path

Tags: java, amazon-s3

while downloading the object from amazon s3 i cant able to download it to diffrent folder rather then the file uploaded path...why it is happening like this may be it is metaData problem....please post your valuable comments Thanks in advance..below am posting the code for upload and download

```
                 public void AmazonUpload(String fileObj) throws IOException {
    try {
        this.key = fileObj;
        try {
            if (this.key == null) {

            } else {
                if (readFile(this.key) != null) {
                   // this.key="1";
                    this.putObjResult = this.amzObj.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketName, this.key, readFile(this.key)));
                    }
            }
        } catch (AmazonServiceException ae) {
            System.out.println(ae.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AthinioCloudMigration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
           public void AmazonDownload(String dirName, String xmlFilename, String amazonid) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException, IOException {
    String cloudid;
    cloudid = amazonid;
    this.comm = new CommonResources(xmlFilename);

    this.RequestFiles=new ArrayList();
    try {
        this.RequestFiles = this.comm.getXML(cloudid);
        if (this.RequestFiles != null) {
             int len = this.RequestFiles.size();
             System.out.println(len);
            for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
                this.CRobj = (CommonResources) this.RequestFiles.get(index);
                if (cloudid.equals(this.CRobj.getCloudID())) {
                  this.newFile = new File(dirName + this.CRobj.getFileName().concat(".rec"));
                   System.out.println(newFile);
                   newFile.createNewFile();
                    this.metaData = this.amzObj.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(this.bucketName, (dirName + this.CRobj.getFileName())), this.newFile);
                    System.out.println(metaData);
                     java.io.File tmp = new java.io.File(dirName + this.CRobj.getFileName());
                    System.out.println(tmp);
                       tmp.delete();
                                                                           76,23         87%
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in Amazon S3 there is no folder structure you receive everything as a object.

**For Example**: In your bucket you store file in a folder like structure but when you request fro the objects from S3 you will receve your file like `folder1/folder2/demo.txt`.

So try this one, Get the `InputStream` for the S3 for your file like `amazonS3.getObject(bucket, "folder1/folder2/demo.txt").getObjectContent();`. After getting your `InputStream` pass your File Name, Download location and `InputStream` to the below method. If you use `Java 7` use `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(fullPathWithFileName).getFileName().toString()` to get file name from your object name.

```
        public void saveFile(String uploadFileName, String path, InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            File newDirectory = new File(path);
            if (!newDirectory.exists()) {
                newDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            File uploadedFile = new File(path, uploadFileName);
            out = new FileOutputStream(uploadedFile);
            byte[] fileAsBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(fileAsBytes);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dos.write(fileAsBytes);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (dos != null) {
                    dos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```